# Sending JSONString within URL in doPost method, JAVA

Tags: java, json, url, urlencode

I have a json string, needs to be passed as a query parameter of URL.

```
String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"sample\"}";

HTTPSClientUtils.doPost(new URL(url + "?params=" + jsonString), "", header);
```

I tried like this and got error as "Illegal characters in URL"

Then, alternatively, I tried as,

```
String urlJson = URLEncoder.encode(jsonString, "UTF-8");
```

Now also it returns same error.
Can someone guides a proper way to send json string in URL for POST?

Comment: But why are you trying to pass a json in URL, when you can pass the same in the body?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpURLConnection` class with `URL` class and use `OutputStream` to write it in the post body.

```
String postParam = "{\"name\":\"sample\"}";
URL url = new URL(*Your url goes here*);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(postParam.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

You might want to put this in a try-catch body, it throws `MalformedURLException`